# trying to hide specific text by css

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to hide a specific text on my site. The code looks like this:

```
<h1 class="page-header-title" style="user-select: auto;"> == $0
   <span style="user-select: auto;">Showing posts from </span>
   "[Category:]"
   <span style="user-select: auto;">action</span>
```

I only want to hide the text "Showing posts from", but when I use this on `css`:

```
h1.page-header-title {
     display: none;
}
```

It will hide all the texts included the one in `h1` code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add anything to the HTML for this.

You can select the first span element that is a direct child of the h1.

```
h1.page-header-title > span:first-child
```

This says 'find all the h1 elements with page-heade-title class. Then look at all its direct child elements and select the first span you come across'.

```css
h1.page-header-title>span:first-child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="page-header-title" style="user-select: auto;"> == $0
  <span style="user-select: auto;">Showing posts from </span> "[Category:]"
  <span style="user-select: auto;">action</span>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `class` inside `span` tag and then use the class to specify that it needs to be hidden.

```
<span class="span-hide" style="user-select: auto;">Showing posts from </span>
```

```
.span-hide {
display: none;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but the problem is I am very new to running website and I actually only able to edit css I do not know where to edit that span and classes. I have able to see them by pressing F12 on my website thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
    <h1 class="page-header-title" style="user-select: auto;"> 
    <span class='hidden-text' style="user-select: auto;">Showing posts from </span>
    "[Category:]"
    <span style="user-select: auto;">action</span></h1>

    <style>
        .hidden-text{
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong is telling the web to hide everything which has class
`page-header-title` which will hide everything which has this class. If you want to hide that particular span field you have to give that span its different identification. Such as a class or an id.

```
<span class="non-visible-text" style="user-select: auto;">Showing posts from </span>
```

In css you can do

```
.non-visible-text{
display:none
}
```